# Template Non-Type argument, pointer to member data

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, non-type

In ISO_IEC_14882-2011 is written
Addresses of array elements and names or addresses of non-static class members are not acceptable template-arguments.

```
[ Example:

template<int* p> class X { };
int a[10];
struct S { int m; static int s; } s;
X<&a[2]> x3; // error: address of array element
X<&s.m> x4; // error: address of non-static member
X<&s.s> x5; // error: &S::s must be used
X<&S::s> x6; // OK: address of static member

—end example ]
```

So I wrote this small example and came across to not-understandable situation.

```
struct S
{
    int m;
    static int s;
} s;

template <int* p>
void foo()
{}

template <typename T, int T::* p>
void goo()
{}

int main()
{ 
   foo<&S::s>(); // **1. CASE** OK s is static member of struct S
   goo<S, &S::m>(); // **2. CASE** OK, but m is not static member of struct S
   goo<S, &S::s>(); // **3. CASE** error , while s is static member of S
                    // VisualStudio2013 error Failed to specialize function template 'void goo(void)'
}
                    //Clang error: no matching function for call to 'goo' goo<S, &S::s>(); // **3. CASE** error, while s is static member of S
```

So what is the reason that when I parametrized owner of member the situation changed. As described in standard the argument should be address of static data member from class but in 2 and 3 cases vice versa? Any ideas?

Comment: `&S::s` is of type `int*` whereas `&S::m` is of type `int T::*`